# IdentityServer3 - Add token inside token for custom grant type (act-as schema)

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver3, openid-connect

I need to add a token inside a token for an "act-as" schema on a custom grant type in IdentityServer3.
I tried with `PreserveAccessToken` but it just adds the token as a claim in the current ClaimsPrincipal, but can't find a way to nesting it as a claim when getting another token to pass along to the next service/api in the chain.

The idea behind this is for being able to keep an audit of all the hops from the end-user to the last service/api in a chain  of calls.

Comment: Why don't you create a correlationId, and put it as a part of some header instead?

Comment: Because the last link in the chain of calls -an api, for example- that makes the actual call against the DB and tries to record an audit of such operation, should then be able to extract the operation starter (say end-user) and all the services/apis in the middle that were part of the operation. If I am able to make IdSrvr to nest a token inside another, then it should resolve everything without much additional work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a custom grant. This allows extending the token endpoint with custom "operations" - e.g. issuing a token that contains delegated claims - e.g. a token.

docs are here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html

here is also a sample that comes close to your scenario: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Multi%20Hop%20Delegation%20(ActAsCustomGrant)

that said - this is probably the most expensive way to convey a user id over multiple hops.

If there is a trusted subsystem between the back-end system, simply transmitting the required data as payload is much simpler and much faster.

Comment: Yes, I've been experimenting with the Multi-hop sample for quite a while. My problem came up when experimenting with a 3rd API in the chain of calls, as I would lose track of the first one when I get to the 3rd one as it only keeps track of the previous client. My concern with transmitting data on the payload is that I should be delegating to the business logic of the Api a responsibility that I guess should be handled by the authorization/token logic.

Comment: Perhaps what I'm trying to achieve is more related to this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hunt-oauth-chain-01

Comment: Is it possible to use acr values somehow to achieve this?